# Erro ao retornar JSON

Tags: php, json, syntax-error

Tenho uma REST API que funciona corretamente no meu ambiente local mas em produção está cortando uma parte do retorno.

```
{"status":"sucesso","data":{"return":"Inser\u00e7\u00e3o de lead efetuada com sucesso.
```

O correto seria:

```
{"status":"sucesso","data":{"return":"Inser\u00e7\u00e3o de lead efetuada com sucesso."}}
```

O erro que está sendo exibido é este:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unterminated string at line 1 column 87 of the JSON data
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o porque? Deve ser alguma configuração no servidor de produção já que no ambiente local retorna corretamente.

[EDIT]
Estou utilizando Code Igniter, o código que monta o retorno é este:

```
$retorno_api = array(
  'status' => 'sucesso',
  'data' => array(
  'return' => $acao_efetuada.' de lead efetuada com sucesso.')
);
```

E eu retorno utilizando o `response()` da Rest Controller do Code Igniter:

```
$this->response($retorno_api);
```

Comment: Só analisando o código para afirmar qualquer coisa. Não consigo imaginar alguma configuração que fosse interferir nisso.

Comment: Estou utilizando Code Igniter, vou incluir a parte do código que faz o retorno

Comment: Posta a url, ai dá para depurar direto no servidor, ou senão posta o php!

Comment: Tira a variavel $açao_efetuada, e testa se o retorno em json vem com o fechamento correto ou então ao invés de usar o response do code Igniter, usa json_encode do php e testa.